# What does なってる mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, hiragana, reading-comprehension

Can anyone tell me what this means? The only definition I could find was "summer vacation" which made no sense in the context. This is what's on ether side of it:

> これ完全にマウン卜ポジシヨンに**なってる**から!

Comment: What does it say before ト?

Comment: Are you sure that's not a small っ? なってる->なっている->have become.　Likewise with the ヨ.

Comment: @user3856370 なっている very rarely means 'becoming'; it usually means 'have become'.

Comment: @Nothingatall Good point. Edited.

Comment: It might be a small  っ, I'm not sure. The full sentence is これ完全にマウン卜ポジシヨンになつてるから! This is not a dirty manga btw.

Answer (score 3):

> nounになってる =　nounになっている
>   has become noun

You need to be careful to distinguish between the large and small characters.
It's なってる not なつてる and ポジション = "position", not ポジシヨン.

I have no idea what a "mount position" is, but it (これ）has become one. Hopefully you can figure that out from the context of the story.

Comment: マウントポジション [Wiki](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A6%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%83%9D%E3%82%B8%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3#.E3.83.9E.E3.82.A6.E3.83.B3.E3.83.88.E3.83.9D.E3.82.B8.E3.82.B7.E3.83.A7.E3.83.B3) ・[画像](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A6%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%83%9D%E3%82%B8%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ0-XHjOvLAhWI3KYKHe_ABAQQ_AUIBygB&biw=1093&bih=514)

Comment: 'Mount position' is 馬乗り in Japanese. That is a finisher of technique of the Brazilian jiu-jitsu that was introduced from Japan in the Meiji era. :)